# Should I connect a new ceiling fan as the old one was?

Tags: wiring

I have two cables coming into box. Old fan had black and blue attached to the black (hot all the time). The white fan wire attached to other black in the box. The 2 white wires were connected as were the grounds. Should I install new fan the same way?[image]

Comment: Can you add a picture of the wires in the box?

Answer (score 1):

I think the switch was originally on the neutral (downstream) side, which should be corrected. Here's your correct configuration:

Cable 1 is the supply (home run). Cable 2 is the switch loop.

- Blue and black from the fan should connect to 2-black (the return from the switch).
- White from the fan should connect to 1-white (the source neutral).
- The remaining black (source hot) should connect to the remaining white (switch supply).

It's pretty much this, but you'll have a blue along with the black from the fixture.

[image]